# Hudson 3.2.2 does not load

Tags: hudson

I have upgraded hudson to 3.2.2. After replacing the war file and restarting hudson, it gave the option to upgrade some plugins. I upgraded the plugins and then logged into hudson. After this, if I try to move to any other page, the page never loads. The browser just keeps waiting for the page to load. Checked the tomcat logs and did not see any error there. Anyone has any idea, what could be going wrong?

**UPDATE** - The pages do load eventually, but they take a very long time, like 20-30 minutes. Any pointer where to look for issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed by manually deleting a few plugins (cvs, svn, jna support etc.).